# Error at first compilation in flutter(android studio): Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Read time out at java.base

Tags: flutter, compiler-errors

I was trying to compile my first code after installing android studio and flutter when I came across this error. At first, it took a long while for it to compile and run. But then after close to 15secs, I came accross this error.I'd appreciate if anyone has come across this error and knows a way around it.

Tried searching youtube but had no luck. Found some article on git on the same error which stated I should change my date and time to words, but still didnt work

Comment: Hi and welcome! We cannot see your errors. Did you forget to write down the error messages in your question?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.